# Error C2084: function already has a body

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I couldn't figure out what I need to do to fix this error or find anything on this website. Basically I get Error C2084: function 'Calculator::GUI::GUI(void)' already has a body. All I have is a windows form called GUI added to a Win32 application, calculator.

In GUI.h :

```
#pragma once

namespace Calculator {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for GUI
/// </summary>

public ref class GUI : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

void AddControls();
public:
    GUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //


    }
```

and in GUI.cpp

```
#include "GUI.h"

namespace Calculator {

GUI::GUI()
{

}

void DrawButtons();
void DrawLabels();

void GUI::AddControls()
{
    DrawButtons();
    DrawLabels();
}
```

I got what I wanted working by putting everything in the GUI.h file but wanted to have the method's code inside the .cpp file.

Comment: What could that error message possibly mean?

Comment: The compiler itself is telling you. Just view the error in 'Output' window, and see where it is previously implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the header like this:

```
public ref class GUI : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

void AddControls();
public:
    GUI();
}
```

You see, the header should contains declarations only and put implementation into cpp.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with defining the constructor in the header file, if it's short. It just gets inlined.